# What dynamic array formula can I use to calculate runway or burnrate in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I'm using **dynamic array functions in Excel** (SCAN, MAP, LET, BYCOL, etc); wihtout VBA or regular SUMIF formulas, **to create a runway or burnrate-type table**. So, I start with a $10,000 budget, month 1 $2,000 are spent, so $2,000 come out of the budget, month 2 $3,000, and so on until the cash available is 0 for the remaining months of the year. With a table showing how much cash was used from the budget per month, `Desired outcome` in the case below.

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Budget | $10,000 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Month | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | Expense | -$2,000 | -$3,000 | -$7,000 | -$4,000 | -$2,000 |
| 4 | `Desired outcome` | -$2,000 | -$3,000 | -$5,000 | $0 | $0 |

Note that the `Desired outcome` amount is how much of the budget was used to cover the expenses.

Notice that Month 3 I spent $7,000, but from the budget, only $5,000 were left; so that's what I show.

Studied all the dynamic array (SPILL!) functions and lambda functions that I could find on the internet (this video by [excelisfun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45v5NhPhopc&list=PLrRPvpgDmw0m0ZfgxxFf9co6EB2cr_Jyq) is great) but I couldn't make it work. Some combination between `SCAN` or `MAP` would be the go-to solution I would think.

The solution should be one formula that leverage MS365 dynamic array functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used REDUCE to get your result:

```
=LET(budget,  -B1,
     expenses, B3:F3,
DROP(REDUCE(   0,    expenses, 
     LAMBDA(   x,    y,
HSTACK(        x,
               IF( SUM(x,y)>=budget,
                   y,
                   budget-SUM(x))))),
     ,1))
```

It creates a cumulative sum of `expenses` and checks if it's greater than or equal to the `budget` (since your expenses are negatives I converted budget to a negative).

If it is it, the value of expenses is shown, otherwise the remainder of the budget minus the cumulative sum of the expenses.

[image]